# Как загрузить файл на php сервер через java

Tags: php, java

как я могу через java загрузить файл на php сервер?
Вот как я принимаю файл на сервере:

```
$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Zagruzka file na server</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 align='center'>Zagruzka file na server</h2>
    <form method="post" name="upload_form" action="http://localhost/upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5242880" />
        <p align='center'>Max : 5 Mb v kodirovke(UTF-8).<br /><input type="file" name="uploaded_file"><input type="submit"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

// второй файл upload.php
<?php
$MaxFileSizeInBytes = 5242880;
// Разрешение расширения файлов для загрузки
$AllowFileExtension = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'csv', 'rar', 'zip', 'doc', 'pdf', 'djvu','zip');
// Оригинальное название файла
$FileName = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
// Полный путь до временного файла
$TempName = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
// Папка где будут загружатся файлы
$UploadDir = "upl\\";
// Полный путь к новому файлу в папке сервера
$FileName1='name.txt';
$NewFilePatch = $UploadDir.$FileName1;
if($FileName) {
    // Проверка если расширение файла находится в массиве доступных
    $FileExtension = pathinfo($FileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(!in_array($FileExtension, $AllowFileExtension)) {
        echo "Файлы с расширением {$FileExtension} не допускаются";
    }
     else {
         // Проверка размера файла
         if(filesize($TempName) > $MaxFileSizeInBytes) {
             echo "Размер загружаемого файла превышает 5МБ";
         }
          else {
              // Проверяем права доступа на папку
              if(!is_writable($UploadDir)) {
                  echo "Папка ".$UploadDir." не имеет прав на запись";
              }
               else {
                   // Копируем содержимое временного файла $TempName и создаем нового в папке сервера
                   $CopyFile = copy($TempName, $NewFilePatch);
                   if(!$CopyFile) {
                       echo "Возникла ошибка, файл не удалось загрузить!";
                   }
                    else {
                        echo "Файл успешно загружен!<br />Ссылка на файл: <a href='{$NewFilePatch}'>{$NewFilePatch}</a>";
                        echo "<br>";
                    }
               }
          }
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: надо обязательно использовать move_uploaded_file и избегать XSS атак

Comment: http://komotoz.ru/uroki/php/zagruzka_fajlov_na_server.php